# Server restarts with the below error: StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services

Tags: user-interface, customization

I did basic customizations to the dev portal and all was working well. But once I close the react project using ctrl C and subsequently stop the wso2 project using the same command, I get the aside recurring error: **StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services** when I try to start up the project. In short, the apim restarts but it never reaches the point where I can hit the dev portal again. The aside is repeated: **StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services**

I'm using jdk 17, node 16.16 & windows 11

I was expecting that the server would start up successfully, and that the changes that I made on the dev portal would not be lost.